# How can I write my own library for android

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I want to understand how to write a dynamic library .so for android? This is not the usual linux library, is it? And I want to write my own. For example instead of already lying there. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to write native libraries.

Comment: Yes, I work in this direction, but I still don't understand how to do it. 
I can only create a dynamic library, which can only use in my application. (because name of function (in generated header) depends on the java class). So I can't find how to create my library for all applications. Can you suggest any book about it?

Comment: You'd need to reuse the library in each app, the security model doesn't allow installing system wide native code. Alternatively you can provide some sort of wrapper around your native library and expose it as a service. There's probably more alternatives, but perhaps you could be a bit more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: So, android has a lib folder and any application can use these libraries. Is not it? For example cut the rope use opengles library. (libGLESv1_CM.so for example) and I want to know how can I do the same library. For example I'll create my libGLESv1_CM.so and functions from this library will do something different.

Comment: Sorry, you can only install native code for your own app. Unless you have a rooted phone or are assembling your own Android distribution from source.

Comment: But if I can do all what I want with files on android. How can I do it?

Comment: How can you do what? Install system wide libraries? You can't. What makes you think you can? Where did you hear that it's possible?

Comment: What do you mean? I can not copy your library to lib? Or I can not replace libs in root device? Now I work with the virtual machine android x86. And, for example, through safe mode you can do it.